# Пост не отображается в таксономии после добавления его с помощью wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress

Добавляю пост с помощью `wp_insert_post`, все хорошо, все добавляется. Также нужная таксономия проставляется. Но в данной таксономии пост не отображается и начинает отображаться только если в редактировании поста апдейтнуть его, даже ничего не меняя. Куда копать?

P.S. таксономия добавляется через wp_set_object_terms.

```
$post_data = [
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'other',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => [ 1 ],
];

$post_id   = wp_insert_post( $post_data, true );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term_value, 'news', true );
```

Comment: покажите фрагмент кода

Comment: $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'other',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_category' => [1]
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, true);
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term_value, 'news', true);

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него код.

Comment: Отредактировал ваш вопрос.

Comment: А вы уверены, что в момент добавления постов у вас уже есть таксономии? в целом вы можете посмотреть ответ wp_set_object_terms функции и у знать, термин не был добавлен

Comment: Что такое $term_value?

Comment: Да, пробовал и с существующими таксономиями и с новыми. $term_value - название терма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в каких-то плагинах. На чистом WP ваш код работает.

Отключите все плагины, поставьте стандартную тему, добавьте в `mu-plugins` такой файл и убедитесь, что всё работает.

```
<?php

/**
 * Register Notification custom post type.
 */
function so_register_cpt_notification() {
    $labels = [
        'name'               => 'Notifications',
        'singular_name'      => 'Notification',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Notification',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Notification',
        'new_item'           => 'New Notification',
        'view_item'          => 'View Notification',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Notifications',
        'not_found'          => 'Not Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Not Found In Trash',
        'parent_item'        => 'Parent',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent:',
        'menu_name'          => 'Notifications',
    ];

    $args = [
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'description'           => 'Notifications',
        'supports'              => [
            'title',
            'editor',
        ],
        'taxonomies'            => [ 'channel' ],
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        // phpcs:disable WordPress.PHP.DiscouragedPHPFunctions.obfuscation_base64_encode
        'menu_icon'             => 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . base64_encode( '<svg height="20" viewBox="0 85.5 1024 855" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M490.666667 938.666667c46.933333 0 85.333333-38.4 85.333333-85.333334h-170.666667c0 46.933333 38.4 85.333333 85.333334 85.333334z m277.333333-256V448c0-130.986667-90.88-240.64-213.333333-269.653333V149.333333c0-35.413333-28.586667-64-64-64s-64 28.586667-64 64v29.013334C304.213333 207.36 213.333333 317.013333 213.333333 448v234.666667l-85.333333 85.333333v42.666667h725.333333v-42.666667l-85.333333-85.333333z" fill="black" /> </svg>' ),
        // phpcs:enable WordPress.PHP.DiscouragedPHPFunctions.obfuscation_base64_encode
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'rewrite'               => [
            'slug'       => 'notification',
            'with_front' => false,
        ],
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    ];

    register_post_type( 'notification', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'so_register_cpt_notification' );

/**
 * Register taxonomies for Notification custom post type.
 */
function so_register_taxonomies() {
    $args = [
        'labels'            => [
            'name'              => 'Channels',
            'singular_name'     => 'Channel',
            'search_items'      => 'Search Channels',
            'all_items'         => 'All Channels',
            'parent_item'       => 'Parent Channel',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Channel:',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit Channel',
            'update_item'       => 'Update Channel',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Channel',
            'new_item_name'     => 'New Channel',
            'menu_name'         => 'Channels',
        ],
        'description'       => 'Notification Channels',
        'public'            => false,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'meta_box_cb'       => null,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
    ];
    register_taxonomy( 'channel', [ 'notification' ], $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'so_register_taxonomies' );

/**
 * Add post and set term for it.
 */
function so_term_cache() {
    $post_data = [
        'post_title'  => 'Post term cache test',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => 'notification',
        'post_author' => 1,
    ];

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data, true );
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'foobar', 'channel', true );
}

add_action( 'init', 'so_term_cache', 20 );
```

Comment: Не помогло(((((

Comment: Обычно даю ответы уже протестированные, здесь сделал исключение ). Ладно, протестирую позже и дам точно рабочий вариант.

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: Большое спасибо, проблема была с плагином ACF, предыдущий разработчик сделал скрытое поле, в которое при сохранении поста с админки записывалось true